# Inheritance of decorators

Tags: python, function, inheritance

I have 3 files one `person.py` and `items.py` and `game.py`.

In `game.py` there is an event handler such that when a button or space is pressed it calls the player object to use the function given to it by object in his hand.

To achieve this I have created an inheritable item class with a function that when called by the person returns a function specific to the subclass of item.

I have tried to create a decorator function of item `@efunc` that sets the function beneath as a variable of `self.efunc` and a second function to be called by person `inhand.getefunc()` that returns efunc as a variable which is then called by the person when game.py calls that function.

In `person.py`:

```py
class person:
  def init(self):

    self.inhand = banana # this could be many other different items and
    #changes through the game

  def useefunc(self): # game.py calls this function when e is pressed
    func = self.inhand.getefunc()
    func(self)

  def usespacefunc(self):# game.py calls this function when space is #pressed
    func = self.inhand.getspacefunc()
    func(self)
```

In `items.py`:

```
class items:
  def init(self):
    self.efunc
    self.spacefunc

  def efunc(func,self):
    self.efunc = func

  def getefunc(self)
    return self.efunc

  def spacefunc(func,self):
    self.spacefunc = func

  def getspacefunc(self):
    return self.spacefunc

class banana(items):

  def init(self):# was removed
    self.efunc = consume # I tried this it did not work was removed
    self.spacefunc = trash # also did not work was removed
  @spacefunc
  def consume (p):

#p is a person so consume can transfer its effects on the person and its animation
 @efunc
  def trash(p):

class nothing(items):
  pass
```

I have done some troubleshooting and editing and I could not determine much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making things much more complicated than they need to be. It would be much easier for the `Person` object to pass a reference to itself to an appropriate method of the item in its hand.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, in_hand):
        self.in_hand = in_hand

    def use_object(self):
        self.inhand.use(self)

class Item:
    def use(self, person):
        pass

class Banana(Item):
    def use(self, person):
        # do something here?
```

There's no need for decorators or any other complexity.

As for why your code wasn't working, the main issue was that you were trying to use `self` in a context where there was no instance yet. A decorator of a method, for instance, can't use `self` directly, since the method is defined before the class exists yet (and *long* before any instances exist).